# Are there ORMs that handle n+1 issue via multiple queries?

Tags: c#, orm

We are currently using hand built queries for retrieving parts of our object model, but would consider moving to an ORM if we knew we could get it to do some of the optimizations that we get. Particularly when it comes to the N+1 problem.

Lets say you have object A, which for each A there is a list of B and a list of C.

We want to retrieve a list of A's, based on a filter, along with their B's and C's

We currently are able to do this with 3 queries, independent of the number of As returned. Basically we build the query for A, with all of its filter clauses, and then query the B's using a query like

"SELECT b.* FROM B b WHERE b.a_id IN ( SELECT a.id FROM ..... clause built for the query for A...)"

We then do the same for C and combine the results into our A objects.

I've looked at NHibernate and EF, but I've never seen any examples where the framework ends up sending multiple queries for a single entity request.

Any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Most modern ORMs use a join rather than multiple calls. In your example, it would be `SELECT A.*, B.*, C.* FROM A, B, C`, rather than `SELECT * FROM A` `SELECT * FROM B`, `SELECT * FROM C`. This does fall apart for more complicated queries, though (such as paging, potentially). That being said, you can leverage the ORM to make multiple queries as you're already doing, anyway.

Comment: @Rob The issue with that is if you have 10 B's and 10 C's for each A, and you need 10 columns for A, you end up retreiving 100 times the number of records, plus if B and C are small, it's completely overkill. I'm surprised that most modern ORMs can't figure out how to make the queries on B and C separately using the selection clause for A.

Comment: You're right, it's a bit of a waste. Locally testing though, LINQ2Sql actually does both (it'll do the first child relationship with a join, and for each subsequent relationship it'll do `SELECT * FROM C where AId = xyz`). How it determines which is which, I'm unsure.

Comment: @Rob, are you saying that LINQ2Sql does a query for each A? That creates an n+1 problem, which we're trying to avoid. I'm not sure why it wouldn't do a SELECT * FROM A WHERE ..., to fill A, then SELECT * FROM C c JOIN (SELECT id FROM A WHERE ...) a ON c.a_id = a.id, to fill the lists of C's for each A.

Comment: Actually yes, you're correct. I imagined it would do the `SELECT * FROM C` for the set of `A`'s primary keys (I was artificially limiting `A` to 1 row when testing), but that seems not to be the case. It is indeed N+1.